# MERGE statement using OUTPUT with WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert data from one system into another so I keep an intermediate mapping table to keep the ids from old and new table.

I'm using a `MERGE` condition, is there any way to

```
DECLARE @TenantId INT = 1

MERGE dbo.[Account] AS t
USING (SELECT  m.[AccountId],
               m.[TenantId],
               a.[ID_Account],
               a.[Account_No],
               a.[Account_Name],               
          FROM [Client1].dbo.[Account] a
          LEFT JOIN migration.[Account] m ON m.[ID_Account] = a.[ID_Account] AND m.[TenantId] = @TenantId
      ) AS s
ON (t.[AccountId] = s.[AccountId] AND t.[TenantId] = s.[TenantId]) 

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([TenantId], [Number], [Name], [Active] )
    VALUES (@TenantId, s.[Account_No], s.[Account_Name], 1)
    OUTPUT @TenantId, inserted.[AccountId], s.[ID_Account] INTO migration.[Account];
```

This is fine, but if I try to run it a second time, the records are inserted again on my migration.[Account] table keeping repeated data. Is there any way to put a where condition on the output?

Comment: Can you show some sample data, a *complete* `MERGE` statement, and explain how you expect things to work when you run this merge twice?

Comment: If you are getting duplicates, it sounds like the condition(s) of the `MERGE` are not correctly identifying the records when they are matched and when they are not matched.  Without anything else specified, the `NOT MATCHED` is the same as `NOT MATCHED BY TARGET`.

Comment: Am I right, that the "real" destination table works fine and only the "historical" table - to track your changes - has duplicates? In this case it might be a possibility to put a trigger on this table...

Comment: To find the issue in your matching, run a SELECT on the accountId and TenantId of the duplicates. I suspect that one of the two is unique, which is why your `MERGE` is inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check to see if values from the source exist in the target, you check to see if the AccountId from migration.Account is equal to the AccountId from dbo.Account.  You output the results to the migration table, but the original record still exists so it will be included in subsequent executions of the merge.

To fix your problem you need to either:

- delete the original record
- Add an isUpdated column in the migration table that you update after insertion and will prevent the source from being loaded.
- Update the AccountId with the new AccountId so it will match the condition on subsequent executions.
- Have the new record somehow cancel the original in the source record.

Here's a method with a new isUpdated and updates the accountId column:

```
UPDATE m SET
  isUpdated = 1,
  AccountId = o.NewAccountId
FROM migration.Account [m]
INNER JOIN (
    MERGE dbo.[Account] AS t
    USING (SELECT  m.[AccountId],
                   m.[TenantId],
                   a.[ID_Account],
                   a.[Account_No],
                   a.[Account_Name],               
              FROM [Client1].dbo.[Account] a
              LEFT JOIN migration.[Account] m ON m.[ID_Account] = a.[ID_Account] 
                   AND m.[TenantId] = @TenantId
              WHERE m.isUpdated IS NULL OR m.isUpdated = 0
          ) AS s
    ON (t.[AccountId] = s.[AccountId] AND t.[TenantId] = s.[TenantId]) 

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT ([TenantId], [Number], [Name], [Active] )
        VALUES (@TenantId, s.[Account_No], s.[Account_Name], 1)
        OUTPUT @TenantId, s.AccountId [OriginalAccountId], inserted.[NewAccountId]
) [o] ON o.TenantId = m.TenantId AND o.OriginalAccountId = m.AccountId
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is do updates on when matched:

```
MERGE into dbo.[Account] AS destination
USING (SELECT  m.[AccountId],
               m.[TenantId],
               a.[ID_Account],
               a.[Account_No],
               a.[Account_Name],               
          FROM [Client1].dbo.[Account] a
          LEFT JOIN migration.[Account] m ON m.[ID_Account] = a.[ID_Account] AND m.[TenantId] = @TenantId
      ) AS holdinarea
ON (destination.[AccountId] = holdinarea.[AccountId] AND destination.[TenantId] = holdinarea.[TenantId]) 
WHEN  MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE set [AccountId]=holdinarea.accountid,
               [TenantId]=holdinarea.tenantID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([TenantId], [Number], [Name], [Active] )
    VALUES (holdingarea.TenantId, holdingarea.[Account_No], holdingarea.[Account_Name], 1);
```

Comment: I want to insert the ids from old table into new table into my table migration.[Account]. Because is a merge when I run it a second time, records are inserted again on the mapping table but I don't really need it because where inserted before. I can create a temp table and then insert it when not exists but I was wondering if I can do it directly

Comment: OK, so the merge should update when matched and insert when not. As you can see I aliased the first statement(MERGE into dbo.[Account] AS destination) as destination and the using query as holdingarea. When you use the merge statement this way it will not insert again if it's matched. As you can see both update and insert are taking place on the destination table (in this case dbo.account). Records should not be inserted on the mapping table as you insert only on the destination